# Get the column name of random row PHP

Tags: php

I have a table with 5 columns (id, s1, s2, s3, s4) and let's say, 3 rows:

```
First one -> (1, 40, 30, 20, 15) 
Second one -> (2, 22, 32, 45, 18)
Third one -> (3, 89, 24, 65, 12)
```

So I get a random row from the 4 s columns from, for example, the first row id.

```
$query = "SELECT s1, s2, s3, s4 FROM table WHERE id = 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row[array_rand($row, 1)].'<br>';
```

With this, I get, from the id row number 1, a random between the 4 s columns (40, 30, 20 or 15), but what I really want to get is the name of that column, not the value of that field from the column (not the 40, 30, 20 or 15, but s1, s2, s3 or s4) so I can print that name later (so a image or another is loaded if s1, s2, s3 or s4 is chosen) and update the random field with 1 number less (if I got s1, 40 is 39, or if the random was s2, 30 is then 29, and etc, etc).

I dont know if my logic is wrong or I should make a different approach with the tables.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are **deprecated**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_rand` returns the column name. So just assign that to another variable:

```
$col = array_rand($row, 1);
$col_value = $row[$col];
```

Comment: The idea is to get, from the mysqli_fetch, both the name of the column and the index of that column like s1 => 0, s2 => 1, s3 => 2... When I print_tf the result with mysql_fetch_array I get both values, but how do I print the values with the index of the columns, and how do I print the values with the name of the colum, separately? And storing both in 2 vars: a var with the values of the index of the column, and another var with the names of the columns. Any idea ?

You can't do: 
$result = $db->fetch_array(mysqli_num);
$result = $db->fetch_array(mysqli_assoc);

Right ?

Comment: Why do you need the index of the column? Isn't the column name in `$col` good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this:

`echo array_rand($row).'<br>';`